# The application stopped unexpectdly when use GCM

Tags: android

I had error when running the project , I had sent later about this issue but I support with Image. This error I had searched more on the internet but I couldn't find any solution for this issue. I hope if any one help me.

I tested all codes and I found the error to be here:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_elaraby_group);

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

        if (regId.equals("")) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
        }
    }
```

manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.elarabygroup"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ElarabyGroup"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_elaraby_group" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name=".ElarabyGroup" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>


</manifest>
```

[image: error Log Cat]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to run your app on a device or emulator that does not have the Google Services Framework. If you are testing using the emulator, be sure to use an emulator image that has the Google APIs in it.

Comment: I use emulator  also I tested the project on android mobile as Samsung but this error appeared , also what did you mean with Google Services ?

Comment: @user1644081: The Google Services Framework is present on devices that legitimately have the Play Store and related apps on them.

Comment: I downloaded the Google API on Android files but the error still be on the application

Comment: @egydeveloper: "I downloaded the Google API on Android files" -- first, those are not available for download, except by software pirates. Second, AFAIK, they cannot simply be downloaded and made available for use, as they are part of the firmware.